# public void method throws Exception if - JUNIT test: Exception should not be thrown

Tags: java, testing, exception, junit, throw

I have a certain `public void method` which `throws` an `Exception` `if` a condition is fulfilled.
In my case the method looks like this:

```
public void toBeTestedMethod(Testobject testObject) throws CertainException {
if (testObject.getStatus().getAllowsEdit()){
throw ...}
}
```

`getStatus()` is a method which returns a certain Status and `getAllowsEdit()` is a method which returns a `boolean` value and `nullable = true`. For the two methods there also exist set-methods.

Edit1: The test regarding this method when it fails is already running fine:

```
public void testToBeTestedMethod_FailureStatus() throws Exception {
        try {
            TestObject testObject = _testObjectMockDAO.getNewTestObject();
            _testObjectMockDAO.setTestObject(testObject);
            _testObjectBusinessImpl.toBeTestedMethod(testObject);
            
            fail("Check failed");
        } catch (CertainException ex) {
            assertEquals(ErrorCode.WRONG_STATUS, ex.getErrorCode());
        }
    }
```

I would now like to test the method `toBeTestedMethod`. The target is that the method does **not throw** an exception but gets executed successfully.

That means I would like to write a JUNIT-test which tests the following:

```
public void testToBeTestedMethod_success throws Exception{

// Enter test code here

}
```

Edit2 (regarding the `class Status`):

```
public class Status {
...
private String _status;
public String getStatus() {
return _status;
}
}
```

In my opinion, I have to modify the condition in the if-statement in order to get the expected result, correct?

Note: I did not write the method and the other code. Nevertheless, my task is to test the code via JUNIT.
I tried some code, but everytime I get the error that the Excpetion was thrown.

Even if you cannot solve this problem, I would be glad to get some hints where I should look for the problem why my test does not do what I want the test to do.

Comment: can you show what is getStatus and how the class definition looks like

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very abstract and needs more data, I am posting an answer here based on what I have understood.
Here are the classes:

```java
public class SampleTestService {


    public boolean toBeTestedMethod(TestObject testObject) throws AccessViolationException {
        if (testObject.getStatus().getAllowsEdit()) {
            throw new AccessViolationException("Edit is allowed for this non confirmed user");
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    static class TestObject {
        private SomeStatus someStatus;

        public SomeStatus getStatus() {
            return someStatus;
        }
    }

    static class SomeStatus {
        private boolean allowsEdit;

        public boolean getAllowsEdit() {
            return allowsEdit;
        }
    }

    static class AccessViolationException extends RuntimeException {
        public AccessViolationException(String message) {
            super(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Since the method depends on another class and that class-dependent also on another class you need to mock them in the chain. Here is how I have done it:

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class SampleTestServiceTest {

    private final SampleTestService.TestObject mockTestObject = mock(SampleTestService.TestObject.class);
    private final SampleTestService.SomeStatus mockSomeStatus = mock(SampleTestService.SomeStatus.class);

    private final SampleTestService service = new SampleTestService();

    @Test
    void testThatMethodDoesNotThrowsException() {
        when(mockTestObject.getStatus()).thenReturn(mockSomeStatus);
        when(mockSomeStatus.getAllowsEdit()).thenReturn(false);
        boolean result = service.toBeTestedMethod(mockTestObject);
        Assertions.assertTrue(result);
    }

    @Test
    void testThatMethodThrowsException() {
        when(mockTestObject.getStatus()).thenReturn(mockSomeStatus);
        when(mockSomeStatus.getAllowsEdit()).thenReturn(true);
        Assertions.assertThrows(SampleTestService.AccessViolationException.class, () -> {
            service.toBeTestedMethod(mockTestObject);
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think this goes in the right direction. I will edit my question with the test case where it throws an exception. This one already works. And I also try to answer the question you rose regarding the Status class and getStatus()-method.